# Gather browser details used to browse webpage

Tags: browser, html

I am tasked with the development of a web page.

As a part of this, I also need to collect the details of browser used by the users to browse the web page (along with version, timestamp & IP).
Tried searching over the internet but maybe my search was not properly directed.
I am not sure how to go about this.
Any pointer to get me started here would help me a long way.

I would also like to know how to store the information thus collected.

Not sure if this is a good idea - but just thinking out loud  - are there any online service/channel available where the data can be uploaded in real time - like thingspeak.

Thanks

Comment: You mean something server side like checking the log files?

Comment: I am looking for something in Javascript/Jquery that can fetch the browser details for me in a way that I can consume later.Excuse my ignorance here.I am not well versed in web technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics is great, but it doens't give you the data (for free). So if you want your data in e.g. SQL format then I may suggest a you use a tool that collects the data for you and then sends it to Google Analytics.
We use Segment (segment.io, but there are probably other tools out there too) for this, they have a free plan. You will need to create a Warehouse in AWS and all your data will be stored there, incl. details of the browser (version, timestamp, IP).

Disclaimer: I do not work for Segment, but I am a customer.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Google Analytics in your website, then after 1 week, take a look at the Google Analytics page to see data that was collected.

Follow the guide here to configure Google Analytics on your website: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You should go for alternatives like Segment(https://segment.com/), Mixpanel(https://mixpanel.com/) and similars. They can guarantee consistency for your data and also integrate to many different analytics tools and platforms.